# File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options Not available on Azure App Service Linux Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Our .Net Core 5 Website is deployed on Azure Linux web app service. We need to use pipeline variables to substitute the appsettings.json file values but we are not able to see the File Transforms & Variable Substitution Options on azure app service deploy for Linux web app type, like the below image. Any suggestion would be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when moving from Windows to Linux.  You need to add a new task called **File Transform**.  You'll see the *Variables Substitution* section, expand this and select JSON File Format and set the target files.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### Updated Answer

For version 4.* - App Setting and Configuration Settings are available for Azure Linux Web App

[image]

For Task Version 3.*  File Transforms & Variable Substitution is visible

[image]

[image]

Comment: my web app type is not windows, it is the Linux web app type I already mentioned on the topic, for Linux it is not available.

Comment: @DS - Updated the answer please check once and let me know

Comment: thanks for the update, I can see now but there is one problem while downgrading from version 4 to 3, in version 3 there is Connection type is not available -- In our app web deployment connection type is selected as Azure Resource Manager, so there deployment is getting failed if we downgrade --- any way we will use key vault instead of JSON value substitution